# How to recover from the Dash Home appearing behind other running programs?

Tags: 11.10, launcher, unity-dash

Can someone tell me how to recover from the Dash Home screen appearing behind the running programs?  I almost always have more than 50 applications running.  Many times this includes more than 30 Firefox pages.

Every once in a while the Dash Home screen will appear behind all the windows and the only way I can recover from this problem is to Log out and log back in or restart the computer.  This often takes me up to an hour to get back to where I was working with all the applications I'm using back into place.

Is there a way to stop this from happening?  Does this happen to other people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to recover from this by restarting Unity.  You can do this by hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then typing the following:

```
unity --replace
```

This should cause the panel and window decorations to temporarily disappear and then reappear.  You will now have a new instance of Unity managing your windows.

Answer (score 0):

This started to affect me only in the 24hours (eg. 25-Oct), since recent fix/updates were loaded.

Re-starting PC does NOT stop this re-occuring.

This is a known bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/805087

Unable to clear this issue, but it does clear itself (somehow).

Note: entering 'unity& disown' only mucks things badly enough to require a re-start.